# Can you have a default argument with a class function with variadic templates?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

The following is entirely valid if I wanted to have a default argument using variadic templates. I was wondering if something similar could be replicated within a class:

```
inline static constexpr auto myrun_func = [](auto b){std::cout<<b<<std::endl;};


template<class UnaryFunction, class... Args>
struct running_func{
    public:
        running_func(UnaryFunction&& unary, Args... args, const char* str = __builtin_FUNCTION()){
            std::cout<<"function was run from "<<str<<std::endl;
            std::forward<UnaryFunction>(unary)(args...);
        }
    
};

template<class UnaryFunction, class... Args>
running_func(UnaryFunction&& unary, Args... args) -> running_func<UnaryFunction, Args...>;

void test(){
    running_func(myrun_func, 10);
}
```

So the output would be:

```
function was run from test()
10
```

I was wondering if I could do something similar in a class like such:

```
inline static constexpr auto myrun_func = [](auto b){std::cout<<b<<std::endl;};

class foo{
    template<class UnaryFunction, class... Args>
    struct running_func{
        running_func(foo* ex, UnaryFunction&& unary, Args... args, const char* str = __builtin_FUNCTION()){
            std::cout<<"function was run from "<<str<<std::endl;
            std::forward<UnaryFunction>(unary)(args...);
            ex->f();
        }
    };
    template<class UnaryFunction, class... Args>
    running_func(this, UnaryFunction&& unary, Args... args) -> running_func<UnaryFunction, Args...>;
    void f(){
        std::cout<<"f() called"<<std::endl; 
    }
};
void test(){
    foo example;
    example.running_func(myrun_func, 10);
}
```

The following obviously wouldn't work. However, I was wondering if something similar could be employed where the `running_func` struct could access the class.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. The first example is kind of cheating by using a deduction guide, and thus circumventing the usual rules for how function parameter packs are deduced. This is all a bit of an XY problem though, and there might be a solution to the actual problem you have.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is ill-formed, you cannot access types as members (though there is a proposal for it), and `this` cannot be used outside of a bound function context. If you're willing to change the method of access a bit, you can do something like this:

```cpp
inline constexpr auto runnable = [](auto b) { std::cout << b << std::endl; };

/* `$' is a nonstandard identifier but I like how it looks :P */
template <typename...TT> struct $ : std::tuple<TT...> { };
template <typename...TT> $(TT&&...) -> $<TT...>;

struct Foo {
    void f() { std::cout << "f() called" << std::endl; }

    template <typename F, typename...TT>
    void running_func(F&& fn, $<TT...> tup, 
      const std::source_location& sl = std::source_location::current()) {
        std::cout << "function was run from `" << sl.function_name() << "'\n";
        std::apply(std::forward<F>(fn), static_cast<std::tuple<TT...>&>(tup));
        this->f();
    }
};

void test(){
    Foo foo {};
    foo.running_func(runnable, ${ 10 });
}
```

And of course you can also make it a macro, but it makes things less readable:

```cpp
inline constexpr auto runnable = [](auto b) { std::cout << b << std::endl; };

#define CALLER_FUNC your_name_here
#define running_func(...) CALLER_FUNC(std::source_location::current(), __VA_ARGS__)

struct Foo {
    void f() { std::cout << "f() called" << std::endl; }

    template <typename F, typename...TT>
    void CALLER_FUNC(const std::source_location& sl, F&& fn, TT&&...tt) {
        std::cout << "function was run from `" << sl.function_name() << "'\n";
        std::forward<F>(fn)(std::forward<TT>(tt)...);
        this->f();
    }
};

void test(){
    Foo foo {};
    foo.running_func(runnable, 10);
}
```